# What stats test should I use?

Tags: statistical-significance

If BMI data is broken into two groups, those with low BMI and those with high BMI, what statistical test would I use to see if there is a gender difference (male and female) between the two categories of low and high BMI?

Comment: Why not compare BMI for males with BMI for females?

Comment: You can perform a chi squared test of independence. You null hypothesis would be: There is no association between gender and BMI level. Where the alternative hypothesis would be: There is an association. [Here is an example of how to perform a chi squared test of independence using python](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/461111/276652)

Answer (score 4):

If all you have is the data that has already been binned for you, then the appropriate test is a [Chi squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test), on the two-by-two cross tab. This will test against the null hypothesis of no relationship between the rows and columns (in this case, sex and BMI category - it doesn't matter which is row or column).

Any stats package, and even Excel, can calculate the Chi squared test for you.

If you have the actual BMI values then you should avoid doing this categorisation, and instead make use of the much greater information in the continuous variable. So this answer presumes that you don't, you just have "low" or "high", so you have no alternative.

Answer (score 2):

If you have large enough samples, you can go with z-test for comparing two proportions (e.g. proportions for male in the two groups).

Alternatively you can use the $\chi^2$-test of independence for a $2 \times 2$ contingency table.